# HashiCorp Consul JWT based auth method

Tags: jwt, consul, hashicorp

I did set up ‘jwt’ auth method for my Consul data center. The following is the payload I have used while setting up auth method.

`{ "Name": "my-jwt-auth-method", "Type": "jwt", "Description": "my jwt based auth method", "Config":{ "BoundIssuer": "corp-issuer", "JWTValidationPubKeys": [<my public key>] } }`

The auth method setup was successful.

Later, I have framed the request payload as followed for “/acl/login” API
 `{ "AuthMethod": "my-jwt-auth-method", "BearerToken":  "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzb21la2V5Ijoic29tZXZhbHVlIiwiaXNzIjoiY29ycC1pc3N1ZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODc5MjgwNzd9.<signedpart>" }`

The header in JWT token is

```
{“alg”: “RS256”, “typ”: “JWT”}
```

The payload for JWT token I used is

```
{
“somekey”: “somevalue”,
“iat”: 1687928077,
“iss”: “corp-issuer”
}
```

I am sure my token is signed properly using the private key associated with the public key I used as part of setting up auth method. I have checked both by passing acl Bootstrap token as part of Header and by not passing acl bootstrap token as part of header. I am getting permission denied.

May I know what is the reason?
Thank you!